# Foundation 5: Using interchange with lazy loading

Tags: html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, lazy-loading, zurb-foundation-5

So, I am using Foundation 5 as my frontend framework and [lazy-load-xt](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt) for lazy loading.

Now, I need to implement both responsive images and lazy loading.

For responsiveness, I am using Foundation's [Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html)'s `data-interchange` attribute as follows:

```
<img data-interchange="[<img_path_default>, (default)], [<img_path_large>, (large)]">
```

However, for lazy loading using the plugin I mentioned, I need to specify a `data-src` attribute as follows:

```
<img data-src="<img_path>" >
```

My dilemma is I am only able to implement either lazy loading or responsiveness at a time. How can implement both features?